# Разметка элементов tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Как расположить текст или кнопку ровно по середине окна?
Желательно через Grid, если есть возможность.

Comment: через pack не вариант ? https://younglinux.info/tkinter/pack

Comment: ещё посмотрите через place https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736465/how-to-center-a-tkinter-widget

Comment: @Интик через place если мне нужно разместить по середине вверху, то просто указать anchor=center, а если нужно ниже, то указывать Y координату без Х, и якорь. Я правильно понимаю?